# Using SerialPort in Electron with Angular fails at build

Tags: angular, serial-port, electron

I recently began to experiment with Electron and SerialPort and hit a little snag when adding Angular (7+) in the mix.

So here's the problem:

I run the typical angular CLI commands to generate to the app. I add electron and electron-rebuild as dev dependencies. Then add SerialPort as a dependency.

Inside my app.component.ts -

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as SerialPort from 'serialport';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'electron-angular-serialport';

  ngOnInit() {
    SerialPort.list();
  }
}
```

Then I run the npm command to start the ng build process and electron .

```
npm run electron-build
```

And it gets to about 92% and dies with this error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@serialport/bindings/lib/linux-list.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/Users/22arwxpx/Documents/Coding/electron-angular-serialport/node_modules/@serialport/bindings/lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@serialport/bindings/lib/unix-write.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/22arwxpx/Documents/Coding/electron-angular-serialport/node_modules/@serialport/bindings/lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@serialport/bindings/lib/unix-read.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/22arwxpx/Documents/Coding/electron-angular-serialport/node_modules/@serialport/bindings/lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/bindings/bindings.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/22arwxpx/Documents/Coding/electron-angular-serialport/node_modules/bindings'
ERROR in ./node_modules/bindings/bindings.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/22arwxpx/Documents/Coding/electron-angular-serialport/node_modules/bindings'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@serialport/parser-byte-length/byte-length.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/Users/22arwxpx/Documents/Coding/electron-angular-serialport/node_modules/@serialport/parser-byte-length'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@serialport/parser-cctalk/cctalk.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/Users/22arwxpx/Documents/Coding/electron-angular-serialport/node_modules/@serialport/parser-cctalk'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@serialport/parser-delimiter/delimiter.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/Users/22arwxpx/Documents/Coding/electron-angular-serialport/node_modules/@serialport/parser-delimiter'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@serialport/parser-ready/ready.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/Users/22arwxpx/Documents/Coding/electron-angular-serialport/node_modules/@serialport/parser-ready'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@serialport/parser-regex/regex.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/Users/22arwxpx/Documents/Coding/electron-angular-serialport/node_modules/@serialport/parser-regex'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@serialport/stream/stream.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/Users/22arwxpx/Documents/Coding/electron-angular-serialport/node_modules/@serialport/stream'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! electron-angular-serialport@0.0.0 electron-build: `ng build --prod && electron .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the electron-angular-serialport@0.0.0 electron-build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/22arwxpx/.npm/_logs/2018-12-08T03_13_40_398Z-debug.log
```

Is there some other way that I should be importing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer :

1. Install @types/node

   ```
   npm install --save-dev @types/node
   ```
2. Modify your tsconfig.json like so-

   ```
   {
     "compileOnSave": false,
      .....
         "compilerOptions": {
         "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
         "moduleResolution": "node",
         "types": [
             "node"
          ]
      }
    }
   ```

> Take note of `types` and `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` key.

3. Add this to your polyfills.ts

   `(window as any).global = window;`
4. Require serialport

   ```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
   import { } from 'electron';
   import Serialport from 'serialport';

   @Component({
     selector: 'app-root',
     templateUrl: './app.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
   })
   export class AppComponent {

     constructor() {
       //check if platform is electron
       let isElectron: boolean = window && window['process'] && 
          window['process'].type;

      if (isElectron) {
         let serialport: typeof Serialport = window['require']('serialport');
         let app: Electron.App = window['require']('electron').remote;
         console.log(serialport, app, window['process']);
      }
    }
   }
   ```

> Note : You do not directly `require` or `import` native dependencies in angular. Instead we use window['require'] to require the module in our app. The `import` statement above is just used to provide for typings information to typescript.

## Long answer :

See my comment [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9827#issuecomment-435350839).

Comment: Hmmm. Yeah I added the recommended changes and it still won't compile.

Comment: I would just like also to say thank you for taking the time to find and provide your thoughts to this issue.

Comment: I'm working on a similar project that requires to work with multiple native dependencies in angular. My dependencies include electron, serialport, chokidar etc. I've set the project multiple times, and it works all the time. Hard to tell what issue you are facing with this. Could you setup a minimal github repo for me to inspect?

Comment: Great. On it. @ClaytonAllen

Comment: Yep! That worked. I was able to dig down into the console log and found the bluetooth incoming port on the mac. So now I will plug in some Arduino boards and see some other results.